# How to do Insert in many-to-many scenario while working with entity framework for mysql?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, many-to-many

This should be a quite common scenario. Here're the database tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `table1_table2` (
  `ID1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ID2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `fk1_idx` (`ID1`),
  KEY `fk2_idx` (`ID2`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID1`) REFERENCES `table1` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk2` FOREIGN KEY (`ID2`) REFERENCES `table2` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then here's my Program.cs:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (testEntities ctx = new testEntities())
        {
            table1 t1 = new table1
            {
                Name = "t1",
                table2 = new List<table2>()
            };

            table2 t2 = new table2
            {
                Name = "t2"
            };

            t1.table2.Add(t2);
            ctx.table1.Add(t1);

            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

And the annoying error screenshot:
[image]

So guys, help me. What should i do? I feel like getting into a trap the first day I started using mysql connector for .NET in EF scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the error, it seems that you must add t2 before doing the many-to-many relation.

```
         table1 t1 = new table1
        {
            Name = "t1",
            table2 = new List<table2>()
        };

        table2 t2 = new table2
        {
            Name = "t2"
        };

        t1.table2.Add(t2);
        ctx.table2.Add(t2); //Here it is... try that
        ctx.table1.Add(t1);
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter, as the EF is supposed to do the t2 addition automatically. Nevertheless, I still tried and verified. Any other clue?

Comment: look at your entities and make sure you don't leave a datetime field with a null value.

Comment: Try also to add a FK property in the table2 property

Comment: The entity is quite simple. The entire and exact definitions have been posted there. There's no datetime field, and the foreign key associations have been defined for both table1 and table2.